# test.c:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `md5_file'

Tags: c++, c, polarssl

I installed polarssl:

1. make
2. sudo make install

tried to compile very simple file, named `test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "polarssl/md5.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  int i;
  for (i=1;i<1;i++)
  {
    char res[16];
    if (md5_file("file.txt",res) == 0)
    {
      int count;
      for (count=0;count<16;count++)
        printf("%02x",res[count]);
      printf("n");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled it like this:

> gcc -lpolarssl test.c -I /usr/local/include/polarssl/

but it shows me:

```
/tmp/cczptlsk.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `md5_file'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

whats the problem, how to fix it? I know for 100% that polarssl files are in `/usr/local/include/polarssl/`

Comment: You only put the included statement in " " if you start looking in the local directory.  Is the program running from the include folder?

Comment: @Magn3s1um: nope but even if I change " " to < > it gives the same error anyway

Comment: Please try putting the `-lpolarssl` last.

Comment: @jxh: worked! How did you know that?:) Youre the best!

Comment: `/usr/local/include` sounds unusual for libs, but may be libpolarssl,a doesn't contain a definition for this method. Did you check the contents of the lib, e.g. with nm?

Comment: @yak Its the linking that was failing. So, it should has something to do with the linking flags.

Comment: Ah, yes! Didn't spot that: *Order matters!*

Comment: Is polarssl a static library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler will attempt to complete linkage in the order the objects or files are presented. In this case, since you had put `-lpolarssl` first, there were no unresolved symbols needed from that library, so nothing got linked in.

Putting `-lpolarssl` last lets the compiler resolve unresolved symbols from your source file from that library.

Comment: thank you so much, wonderful explanation, now I can fully understand it, cheers:)

Answer (score 2):

Includes are fine.

But linking is wrong. Try to put the `-lpolarssl` last in the linker command.

Then add a `-L` if libpolarssl.a is not found by the linker to point it to the right location.

Comment: So should it be just `gcc test.c -lpolarssl` or `gcc test.c -L /usr/local/include/polarssl/ -lpolarssl
`? this works too

Comment: You can add `-I /usr/local/include/polarssl/` but only if you want to be able to write `#include <md5.h>` instead of `#include <polarssl/md5.h>`, which is probably not necessary. Careful, `-L` is for specifying additional locations for compiled libs, as opposed to `-I` which is for addition locations for headers (#includes).